# Как быстро кропить изображения для Android?

Tags: java, android, bash, cmd

Есть много обоев и есть приложение, нужно обрезать каждое изображение не сжимая, а удаляя лишние пиксели слева и справа, в добавок, надо сделать все изображения под формат mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdp xxxhpi. Но только как это всё автоматизировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например, с помощью программы [*convert*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) из набора программ *imagemagick*.

обрезать изображение можно разными путями, например, с помощью команды [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop).

вот [здесь](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/) множество примеров использования этой команды.

Comment: Спасибо! Это то что нужно!